# Javascript to select a drop down option in a class

Tags: javascript, html

I have a chrome extension that when I click it, it will click all the same element buttons on a page and then after the function is done, I want it to select all the 'P's on the drop down. I have multiple 'pf' classes on the page and will need to set all of the to P. The first function is working, when it gets to the second function, there is an error showing the option.length is undefined. My question is how do it get all the option counts inside a class?

```
function clickUpdate(_callback) {
    var updateArray = document.getElementsByClassName("updateButton");
[].slice.call(updateArray).forEach(function(item) {
    item.click();
});
console.log("this is the array legnth: " + updateArray.length);
_callback();
}

//Get select object
var objSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("pf");

//Set selected
setSelectedValue(objSelect, "P");

function setSelectedValue(selectObj, valueToSet) {
    clickUpdate(function(){
        console.log("I am done with the first function");
    });
for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
    if (selectObj.options[i].text == valueToSet) {
        selectObj.options[i].selected = true;
        return;
    }
}
}

<select class="pf"> 
<option selected="selected" value="">Not Run</option>   
<option value="P">Pass</option> 
<option value="F">Fail</option> 
<option value="N">N/A</option></select>
```

Comment: With ChromeDev tool, You can set a breakpoint on `var objSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("pf");`. and see the value of `objSelect`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
//Get select object
var objSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("pf");
```

This doesn't just return the select dropdown - [it returns an HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) (ie, a group of elements) with *any* elements matching that class name. Even if there's only one present, it'll come back as a collection. But your `setSelectedValue` function isn't expecting a collection, just a single element - that's why you get the `undefined` error.

There are a few ways you can handle this, depending on what you're doing elsewhere on the page:

- You can use `document.querySelector('.pf')` to return the *first* element with that class - do this if you're only going to have one `.pf` on the page, or only want to manage one of them.
- Alternately, you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('pf')[0]` to achieve the same thing.
- Or you can give the select an `id` and use `document.querySelector('#pf')` or `document.getElementById('pf')`
- If, on the other hand, you plan to have multiple `.pf` elements that all work this way...you'll have to do some refactoring first. But that's a whole other discussion.

Comment: [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), *not* an Array.

Comment: True! Good catch.

Comment: Regarding your second dot point, `.getElementsByClassName()` was introduced to IE in version 9, the version *after* `.querySelector()`.

Comment: Huh! Thought it was older. This is what I get for not double-checking browser support details. Thanks, will update.

Comment: While you are at it: you only changed one of your three uses of array. If you add in links to the docs, I can delete my comment.

Comment: Hi I would actaully have mutiple "pf" classes on the page and would have to go through all the 'pf' classes and set everything to 'P'. Could I still use the methods your mentioned above? Or is there another way to do the more efficiently ?